# Wordpress child theme internationalization

Tags: wordpress, themes, translate

I have followed the steps about "Internationalisation" on the wordpress codex page http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

To internationalize a child theme follow these steps:

1. Add a languages directory.
       Something like my-theme/languages/.
2. Add language files.
       Your filenames have to be he_IL.po & he_IL.mo (depending on your language), unlike plugin files which are domain-he_IL.xx.
3. Load a textdomain.
       Use load_child_theme_textdomain() in functions.php during the after_setup_theme action.
       The text domain defined in load_child_theme_textdomain() should be used to translate all strings in the child theme.
4. Use GetText functions to add i18n support for your strings.

What about the last step about using getText functions.
Please give me an example about using the getText function and where should I put these strings?

Answer (score 0):

GetText functions are basically

`__('mystring' , 'mytextdomain')` and `_e('mystring', 'mytextdomain')` which is a wrapper for

```
echo __('mystring', 'mytextdomain')
```

All strings in your theme should be wrapped this way.

This is all detailed in http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers which is a link on the page for creating Child Themes

You should always follow these kind on links in the codex, they give useful information ^^